# Generating a SIMPLE licence key system

Tags: .net, dll, licensing

Every stackoverflow question I read descends into "Everyone can crack it" and "Dont annoy your customers"...

I get that. I want to know to make a basic, totally crackable, easy to pirate and non obtrusive licencing system. In fact, I would be happy if someone was motivated enough to crack my software, it means I am doing the right thing.

The implementation i have in mind is:

Licence key like:

XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

Which then activates with a central database, sending some hardware info (got that code already). If different, user gets a message saying "Hardware changed, by clicking OK you will stop other PCs using this licence from working. Are you sure?" Yes / No

If they proceed it will blacklist the old hardware id with that serial on my server.

What I need is a way to generate a simple serial number, I am happy to use a library but I want to get up and running quickly and get back to development. Whats my best option?

Comment: Check out this question for ready to use solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639571/what-open-source-license-verification-frameworks-are-there/14771485#14771485

Answer (score 2):

Sure enough I found the solution shortly after, thanks DNA, you should have listed it as an answer so I could give you the reputation.

I ended up going with http://skgl.codeplex.com/

Out of the box it gave me the format I was looking for, some extra easy to use features and was a breeze to implement - load the class and call generate or validate.

Answer (score -1):

just do a hash on their email address.